# Log out users from Oracle APEX 5.1. from the server side

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I use Oracle Apex 5.1 + Ora 18XE.
Could some one suggest a way how to log-out particular users in the system in particular but not the same moment of time. It might be session expire "force" or raise specific apex exception which stops the engine for that user(s). Change Authorization procedure is not preferred way, because a log out depends on user activity. App consists of 50 pages and 100 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your attention and suggestions.

After some tests we've decided to use apex application process + pl/sql logic and finally APEX_AUTHENTICATION.LOGOUT.

unfortunately, we did not find any supported way to logout users from the "server side".

Answer (score 0):

There is a set of APEX PL/SQL APIs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEAPI/APEX_SESSION.htm#AEAPI-GUID-710E9F4F-157C-4EBA-BBA9-3E0B9EE4002A). Check out Delete Session.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your response, but there is not such possibility in Apex 5.1

Comment: It's worth looking at the API - there is a procedure to log a user out: https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/APEX_AUTHENTICATION.htm#AEAPI29130

Comment: This API call is not working from the SERVER SIDE, means from another oracle session or job, but it does from the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the apex internal table directly:

```
SELECT * FROM apex_workspace_sessions;
```

You could then also delete a Session like that...

```
DELETE FROM APEX_050100.wwv_flow_sessions$ WHERE ID = :ID;
```

Note that this is unsupported and might not work anymore in the future. It will also bypass logout procedures, although you could implement that manually while deleting.